# Redirecionamento após login laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, orientação-a-objetos, laravel-5, laravel-auth

Bom dia, estou utilizando o scafold de autenticação padrão do Laravel, e reaproveitando a estrutura sobrescrevendo os métodos que preciso pra que se comporte da maneira que eu quero.

Personalizei a model default, consegui fazer autenticar e registrar, tudo ok. No entanto após o registro, eu queria redirecionar o usuário para uma rota minha, de pós cadastro. O laravel me fornece alguns pra isso como o `protected function registered( $user )`, no entanto, tudo que eu faço dentro dele parece que é ignorado. Por conta do middleware `RedirectIfAuthenticated (guest)`.

Já tentei diversas outras formas e meio que a estrutura do laravel me fornece.
Já tentei alterar as variáveis `$redirectTo` do RegisterController e do LoginController, e criar os métodos redirectTo em ambos.

Nada parece funcionar. A controller em questão é essa:

```
/**
     * @Middleware("auth")
     * @Get("Painel", as="painel")
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function painel()
    {
        dump('chegou na home controller');
//      $usuario = auth()->user();
//      if ( $usuario->tipo == 'aluno' ) {
//          $aluno = AlunoModel::where('usuario_id',$usuario->id)->first();
//          return view('home.painel-aluno', compact( 'aluno') );
//      }
    }
```

Estou usando o pacote laravelcollective/annotations, mas acho que não tem influência alguma.

Minha model de user:

```
<?php

namespace ContrateUmAluno\Models\Cadastros;

use ContrateUmAluno\Traits\Uuids;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class UsuarioModel extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, Uuids, SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'usuarios';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        'nome', 'email', 'senha', 'tipo'
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'senha', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->senha;
    }
}
```

RegisterController:

```
<?php

namespace ContrateUmAluno\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use ContrateUmAluno\Models\Cadastros\AlunoModel;
use ContrateUmAluno\Models\Cadastros\EmpresaModel;
use ContrateUmAluno\Models\Cadastros\UsuarioModel;
use ContrateUmAluno\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */
    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = 'painel';
    /**
     * Handle a registration request for the application.
     */
    public function redirectTo() {
        return route($this->redirectTo);
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create([
            'nome'          => $request['name'],
            'email'         => $request['email'],
            'senha'         => $request['password'],
            'tipo_usuario'  => $request['tipo_usuario'],
        ])));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
            ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name'          => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email'         => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:usuarios',
            'password'      => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'tipo_usuario'  => 'required',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return UsuarioModel
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $usuario = UsuarioModel::create([
            'nome'  => $data['nome'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'tipo'  => $data['tipo_usuario'],
            'senha' => bcrypt($data['senha']),
        ]);

        $this->criar_tipo($data['tipo_usuario'], $data, $usuario);
        return $usuario;
    }

    /**
     * @param string       $tipo_usuario
     * @param array        $dados
     * @param UsuarioModel $usuario
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function criar_tipo(string $tipo_usuario, array $dados, UsuarioModel $usuario)
    {
        $usuario_id = $usuario->id;
        if ( $tipo_usuario == 'aluno' ) {
            AlunoModel::create([ 'nome' => $dados['nome'], 'usuario_id' => $usuario_id ]);
        } else {
            EmpresaModel::create([ 'nome' => $dados['nome'], 'usuario_id' => $usuario_id ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Após algumas tentativas de alterar manualmente todos os lugares que está escrito `/home` (o que não me parece correto, já que temos a herança pra não precisarmos fazer isso) eu consigo com que ele jogue a rota `/Painel`, no entanto o navegador acusa redirecionamento incorreto.
[image: Imagem do erro em questão]

PS: na print está /login, mas é porque eu tinha removido o middleware pra fazer alguns outros testes.

Eu já não sei mais o que testar e como tentar. Pelo que já procurei nas issues no github, já tem reports desse mesmo padrão, no entanto todas as soluções que foram dadas, não funciona, eu consigo jogar pra rota em questão, mas me acusa esse erro. E alguns casos das issues, era apenas uma questão de estar invertendo o uso da variavel $redirectTo e dos métodos `autenticated` e `registered`.

Desde já, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você está usando rotas por annotation, verifique se o controller do painel está usando o middleware "web", pois sem ele o Laravel não inicia, nem lê a sessão do usuário nessa rota.

Comment: Realmente, era isso mesmo.
Obrigado!