# Login customizado Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, autenticação

Estou tentando fazer um login customizado no Laravel 5.5, consigo até autenticar o usuário, mas quando direciono para outra pagina ele perde a referência do usuário autenticado e redireciona para a tela de login novamente.

Minha classe LoginController:

```
    public function attempt(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'cpf'   => 'required',
        'login' => 'required',
        'senha' => 'required',
    ]);

    $dados = $request->all();
    $pessoa = Pessoa::where('login', $dados['login'])
        ->where('cpf', $dados['cpf'])
        ->first();

    if ($pessoa == null) {

        return redirect()->back()
            ->with('fail', 'Credenciais não encontradas para o login e CPF informados')
            ->withInput();

    }

    if (md5($dados['senha']) != $pessoa->senha) {

        return redirect()->back()
            ->with('fail', 'Senha incorreta para o login ' . $dados['login'])
            ->withInput();

    }

    if (!$pessoa->ativo) {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->with('fail', 'O login não está ativo')
            ->withInput();          
    }

    \Auth::loginUsingId($pessoa->id);

    return redirect()->route('dashboard.index');



}
```

E o meu Model Pessoa:

```
  
class Pessoa extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';


    protected $fillable = [
        'nome', 'cpf', 'senha', 'ativo', 'login',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'senha',
    ];
}
```

Tem algum método ou atributo que eu preciso sobrescrever para resolver isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Auth::login($user, true);
```

deve resolver

Answer (score 0):

Você tem alguns métodos que pode sobrescrever, na sua model que substitui a User default, você tem que colocar um data mutator, parecido com esse:

```
getPasswordAttribute() { return $this->seu_campo_de_senha; }
```

Vou deixar 2 posts meus com esse problema. O segundo era erro de middleware, então você pode pegar ele, que ta mais atualizado. Nele eu sobrescrevo vários métodos que o provider do laravel trás por default.

E lembre-se, no arquivo config/auth.php de alterar a referência da model User, para a sua model em questão.

[Mais antigo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/187488/personalizando-uma-model-de-usuarios-laravel-5-4-problema-no-login)

[Mais recente, mais completo e mais sobrescrito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/314091/redirecionamento-ap%c3%b3s-login-laravel-5-5)

[Referência](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication)

Comment: Sobrescrever o getAuthPassword não resolveu. Sim, o config/auth.php esta direcionando para o model Pessoa. Tanto que quando eu dou o loginByUser ele está autenticando (se eu der um Auth::User logo após a linha do loginbyuser ele esta retornando a instancia do usuario), mas quando eu tento pegar o usuario autenticado na proxima pagina, ele não retorna nada.

Comment: Confere se está startando a sessão.
Tive um caso que estava usando annotations, e ele não startava o middleware web (que é responsável pela session), tive que adicionar nas minhas anotações de rota, o middleware manualmente.